# DateRangePicker not firing "Apply" event after the first Apply

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker

I'm trying to use 7 Daterangepickers for planning 7 daterange one after the others.
The idea is the following: when a daterange is selected clicking on "Apply", all the following daterange auto-update choosing following dateranges.

```
$('.sprintdate').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
  var sprintid = $(this).data("sprintid");
  var start = new Date(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  var end = new Date(picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  var i;
  var k = 0;
  for (i = sprintid+1; i <= 6; i++) {
    var startNew = new Date();
    var endNew = new Date();
    startNew.setDate(end.getDate() + 1+k*14);
    endNew.setDate(end.getDate() + (k+1)*14);
    k++;
  
    $("#sprint"+i).daterangepicker({      
      startDate: moment(start New).format('MM/DD/YYYY'),
      endDate: moment(endNew).format('MM/DD/YYYY'),
      locale: {
        format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
        "firstDay": 1
      }
    }).effect("highlight", {color: '#58D68D'}, 1000);     
  }
});
```

The previous code works, but only for the first "Apply"; after that, the following dataranges will not auto-update.
Am I updating Startdate and EndDate in a wrong way?!?

Answer (score 0):

And the answer was: YES, I was updating Startdate and EndDate in the wrong way.
Here it is the correct version to do it!

```
$("#sprint"+i).data('daterangepicker').setStartDate(moment(startNew).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
$("#sprint"+i).data('daterangepicker').setEndDate(moment(endNew).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
```